# Error: Cannot find module './formats' when deploying node app on heroku server

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have created free account on heroku. I am trying to deploy a node app on this but this showing the following error.

```
2017-06-19T11:25:53.680527+00:00 app[web.1]: > mypu@1.0.0 start /app
2017-06-19T11:25:53.680528+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-06-19T11:25:53.680528+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862204+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:471
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862207+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862208+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862209+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862210+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './formats'
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862211+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862212+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862212+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862213+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862229+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:4:15)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862230+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862231+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862231+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862232+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.862233+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-06-19T11:25:53.872899+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-19T11:25:53.886139+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-06-19T11:25:53.886419+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-06-19T11:25:53.886602+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.11.0
2017-06-19T11:25:53.886778+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-06-19T11:25:53.886955+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-06-19T11:25:53.887988+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mypu@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888109+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888249+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888373+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mypu@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888490+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888603+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mypu package,
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888719+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889463+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889701+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890263+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.898834+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-19T11:25:53.899088+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.899216+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888719+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889463+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889701+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890263+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.898834+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-19T11:25:53.899088+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.899216+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888719+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889463+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889701+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890263+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.898834+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-19T11:25:53.899088+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.899216+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888719+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889463+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889701+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890263+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.898834+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-19T11:25:53.899088+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.899216+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2017-06-19T11:25:53.888719+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889463+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889701+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.889807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890263+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls mypu
2017-06-19T11:25:53.890433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Same application works on my local machine fine. Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "mypu",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mypu",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start" : "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "connect-timeout": "^1.8.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "generic-pool": "^2.4.2",
    "log4js": "^1.1.1",
    "multer": "^1.2.0",
    "mysql": "^2.10.2",
    "requestify": "^0.1.17"
  }
}
```

What could be the issue? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, there was `node_modules` directory present in my repository. I excluded that from github repository and deployed again. Now it is working

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this error occurred due to the missing module as in your case **Error: Cannot find module './formats'**. You have to clean the existing **node_modules** directory and run the `npm install`
to freshly install all the dependencies. If still you are facing issue in deployement then please go through this links for more details

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Fu39V6T_G0

Answer (score 2):

Remove cache of node_modules and redeploy it:

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
```

and then `git push heroku master`

You can also disable the cache if you don't want cache node_module while re-deploying:

```
heroku config:set NODEMODULESCACHE=false
git commit -am 'rebuild' --allow-empty
git push heroku master
heroku config:unset NODEMODULESCACHE
```

This worked for me!